# What does "fix network problems" actually do?

Tags: windows-7, networking

When a network connection doesn't connect to the internet, Windows pops up a dialogue, asking whether you want to "Fix network problems".

What does it actually do when you click "yes"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It checks for and fixes a number of specific known possible problems including problems with DHCP, DNS and adapter configuration.  Microsoft has posted the complete list at [When to Run the Fix My Network Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc513946%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).